# Disambiguating (enum, method, class or struct) with same name in different namespaces

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm having an issue resolving an ambiguity error with an entity existing in different namespaces but they have the same name.

```
namespace A {void Name();}   // Assume this is expanded to have all the code necessary.
namespace A::B {int Name();} // Different method, same name.

namespace C 
{
  using namespace A;
  using namespace B;

  Name();  // error: reference to 'Name' is ambiguous
}
```

While I have access to the code, I need to find the least intrusive solution. The obvious solution would be:

```
#define Name A::Name
```

In C# I could just write `using Name = A::Name;` but C++ still complains.

Comment: Could you not use `using` and fully qualify the references instead?

Comment: That shouldn't compile even if `Name()` is not ambiguous. `using A::Name;` should otherwise work. Or just `A::Name` as suggested.

Comment: Fix the code by using the full name `A::Name`.  Or write `using A_Name = `A::Name` and then replace `Name` By `A_Name` in your code. With find and replace or using compiler error list, you should be able to do hundreds of fixes in a few minutes. No reason to use macros here.

Comment: You can’t just call a function in a namespace like that.  What’s your actual code do?

Comment: `#define Name A::Name` Don't do that! Never do that! This would make the token `Name` unusable. E.e. `class MyClass { void Name(); }` would result in a strange error message.

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces exist to ensure that such name collisions don't happen. That's the whole point of the tool. You have two entities named `A::Name` and `A::B::Name`. They're already unambiguous.

They only *become* ambiguous because you're trying to avoid using their full names. If you want to just call it `Name` within some namespace, then you're going to have to pick *which* `Name` you're talking about.

Unless you're willing to use their full name, you can only `using namespace` one of those names. Even the finer-grained `using A::Name` won't help if you *also* `using A::B::Name`.

Basically, stop trying to fight namespaces and just use them.

Comment: This is the code I inherited, or to be exact, the code that broke because of `Name()` being added to `namespace B`
I just want to fix the broken code with the least impact on the existing QAed code.
So the question is how can I tell the compiler to use `A::Name()` when it sees `Name()` in this file? `#define Name A::Name` works but is there a better way?

Comment: @CJ1: No, there is no other way. Things like this are *why* `using namespace` (especially in *headers*) is considered dangerous. Once a name is made available, it's made available and cannot be made unavailable.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Oh well, `#define Name A::Name` it is.
You'd think that `using Name=A::Name` should work, but no, that would be too simple, instead I need to use the pre-processor to solve this.